# Mosfet as a switch (on/off) and ground isolation

Tags: mosfet, ground, isolation

my question is simple (I hope)

So I have DC in.
 On both + and ground line I have 2 mosfets (one for each line) (driven externally)

When I switch off both Mosfets , can I claim "full galvanic isolation" ?

Is there any leakage current or high frequency noise passing through a switched off mosfet ?

Comment: There is if one side of the circuit becomes connected to a voltage greater than the FET breakdown rating.

Comment: A bigger problem is if the common mode voltage overcomes the gate reverse bias and causes the FETS to start conducting.

Comment: @JohanB: (1) Do your MOSFETs have built in reverse diodes? You can't turn these off. (2) I suspect that you are not asking the real question but trying to justify a (flawed?) design that is proposing to use transistors to provide electrical safety isolation. Can you put me at ease?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't claim "full galvanic isolation".

1. Because there's no such thing. Legitimate isolating products claim things like "galvanic isolation to 6000 V" or "galvanic isolation to 10,000 V" and cite a relevant standard such as UL1577 or IEC 60747-5-5 that sets out how that isolation is specified and tested.

   Even these products might fail to provide isolation if too high a voltage is applied between isolated terminals.
2. Because a MOSFET alone is not going to provide this kind of isolation. A high enough voltage (more on the scale of 100 V than 5000 V) will cause breakdown of the device and make hazardous voltages accessible on the other terminals of FET.

   Maximum \$V_{ds}\$ and \$V_{gs}\$ values will be specified in your MOSFET's datasheet, and unless you're looking at some exotic device designed for use on the power grid and costing $100's, the limit will be much lower than the isolation values appropriate for galvanic isolation.

> Is there any leakage current or high frequency noise passing through a switched off mosfet?

This is irrelevant to the question of galvanic isolation.

But yes, high frequency signals can be coupled between the gate and drain or source, since they're only separated by the gate capacitance.

And leakage current will flow from drain to source (or vice versa). This will be specified in your MOSFET's data sheet.

Answer (score 1):

MOSFETs, like all semiconductors are non linear resistors. When off, the MOSFETs may present a very high resistance indeed, but it is still just a resistance.

As such you can not claim "full galvanic isolation".

Leakage current would be very small however noise is a different entity. Since MOSFETs are capacitive in nature, a considerable amount of AC noise can be transferred through them, even at relatively low frequencies.

Comment: So this capacitance in mosfet.. is drain to source and gate to drain . By choosing a mosftet that has the lowest capacitance on those I should be able to limit any noise coming in (and yes AC is the main worry. Of course I could use mechanical relays to get "full galvanic isolation"

Answer (score 0):

Also, power MOSFETs have an inherent zener diode between the gate and source.  In one direction, the zener voltage is equal to or greater than the device max drain-source voltage spec.  In the other direction it looks like a not-very-efficient power rectifier.  Here is a typical datasheet with the diode shown on page 1.

https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irf540npbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355e39f0d19a1